# multiple snippet for android google map marker

Tags: android, google-maps

can i have multiple snippet in my marker?  I need to use additional information from it. this is my current code. I want to add telephone number information here and set the data to the intent.

```
  //Adding marker on the GoogleMaps
  private void addMarker(LatLng latlng,final String location2, final String address2) {
  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
  markerOptions.position(latlng);
  markerOptions.title(location2);
  markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Store));
  markerOptions.snippet(address2);
  map.addMarker(markerOptions);

  map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle(),1000).show();// display toast

        //Create Intent object
        Intent openNewActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Shop_Details.class);

        //Directly set data in intent object
        openNewActivity.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
        openNewActivity.putExtra("address", marker.getSnippet());

        startActivity(openNewActivity);

      }
  });

}
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461348/making-a-marker-carry-custom-info-to-be-used-when-clicked-android-google-maps/26461727#26461727