# android google map v2 dynamic custom info window pass value

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I am pulling dynamic data from parse and putting the coordinates to google map as marker, my problem is I can't pass the id when custom info window is clicked.

What i want is to show another intent for user profile when the marker is clicked.

My code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> verifiedUsers = ParseQuery.getQuery("VerifiedUsers");
verifiedUsers.whereEqualTo("hideLocation", false);
verifiedUsers.whereEqualTo("isVerified", true);

ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();     
query.whereNear("currentLocation", currentLocation);
query.whereEqualTo("emailVerified", true);          
query.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "userId", verifiedUsers);
query.whereWithinKilometers("currentLocation", currentLocation, 50);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

@Override
public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e == null){
        for(final ParseUser user: users){   
            ParseGeoPoint userLocation = (ParseGeoPoint) user.get("currentLocation");

            LatLng position = new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude());

            Marker gMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker))
                .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left                            
                .title(user.getString("name") + ", andrian")            
                .snippet("Position: " + user.getString("position"))
                .position((position) ));                            
        }
    }                       
}

});

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User ID: " + iNeedIDHere, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Show your Custom info window code.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461348/making-a-marker-carry-custom-info-to-be-used-when-clicked-android-google-maps/26461727#26461727

Comment: Post your code here.