# Passing an Object in marker Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

How do i pass an object on Google maps Marker? so that when i click I can pass the data on the new activity? Is this possible or any way how to do it?

Sample Code

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            LogUtil.d("onMarkerClick");
            MyMarkerObj obj = getMyMarkerObj (); 
            mListView.setSelection(obj.id);
            return false;
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            MyMarkerObj obj = getMyMarkerObj (); 
            intent.putExtra("MyMarkerJson" , gson.ToJson(obj));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you really need to pass the `whole` marker?

Comment: Does your `obj.id` working? if yes, we can impement `Parcelable` for `MyMarkerObj`

Comment: oh. not really. its just a sample code of what i  want to happen. my current implementation is I convert obj to json and put it on snippet. the problem is that the snippet are shown with a json string

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461348/making-a-marker-carry-custom-info-to-be-used-when-clicked-android-google-maps/26461727#26461727

Comment: To clarify thing, do you want to pass `MarkerOptions`?

Comment: @Milk why dont we pass it directly then? I checked it and its implementing `Parcelable`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `MarkerOptions` because it implemented `Parcelable` :

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html

So, my idea is to create an instance of `MarkerOptions` and pass it to other `Activity` with `putExtra` method.

Comment: @Milk yes, let me know the result :)

Comment: can't attain what i want. but thnx

Comment: @Milk What do you mean by cant attain? Please update your code, show us what you did.